# Correct approach for evaluating correlation between multiple measurement devices used on the same subject (repeated measures)

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, agreement-statistics

My scenario is as follows. I am using three different devices (TempDeviceA, TempDeviceB, and TempDeviceC) to take the temperature of each animal in a group every day over several weeks. TempDeviceC is considered the gold standard for temperature measurement of animals. TempDeviceB and TempDeviceC measure temperature by targeting a different part of the animal's body and are more accessible and easier to administer compared to TempDeviceA.

I want to determine the degree of correlation between the temperature values provided by each device (i.e. TempDeviceA vs TempDeviceB, TempDeviceB vs TempDeviceC, TempDeviceA vs TempDeviceC) where each measure is taken one after the other from each pig in the group on a given day. I'm assuming what I want to establish here is the degree of concurrent validity for TempDeviceB and TempDeviceC.

What would be the best approach to utilise here? I came across [this article on repeated measures correlation](https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/psychology/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2017.00456/full) which sounds like it aligns with what I wanted to achieve, but I wanted to ask here as well. Would this be the appropriate approach to use to establish the degree of correlation between the tempDevices and thus concurrent validity of tempDeviceB and tempDeviceC as measures of animal temperature?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that correlation is the right measure to evaluate reliability? (I assume reliability here means agreement with the gold standard). Note that `correlation(X, Y) = correlation(X, Y + 100)`. So the "agreement" between X and Y can be low, yet the correlation can be high.

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov for your reply. Thinking about it further, I think what I'm actually trying to establish is the degree of concurrent validity between the various devices. TempDeviceC is the gold standard and I expect some difference in the temperature values obtained by TempDeviceB and TempDeviceC as these measure the animal's temperature using methods that target a different part of the animal's body.   

I'll update my original post to clarify this, but

Comment: I suggest you also take a look at the [Analysis of Observer Variability and Measurement Agreement](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/obsvar) of @FrankHarrell's [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/). An important point to decide is whether the three devices are intended to measure the same temperature (by different methods), or three different but correlated temperatures.

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov, I'll check these resources out in detail.

Comment: You could also look through the tag [tag:agreement-statistics], (and maybe add it!)

Comment: Thank you @kjetilbhalvorsen, I will do this too.